# git rebase - does pick effectively do nothing?

Tags: git, git-rebase

Say I want to do an interactive `git rebase`.

I use `git rebase -i HEAD~2` and end up in the editor with 2 lines starting with `pick`. If I go ahead and exit the editor then I get the message `Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.`.

The last few commits all seem identical. So, am I right that, in this case, if I simply use `pick` then I am not making any change to the history of my git project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct. A better name for `pick` might be `keep` since if you omit the `pick` commits from an interactive rebase, their changes will be discarded by the interactive rebase.

You can also use `pick` to change the order that the commits are applied in the rebase by moving the `pick` lines up or down in the initial editing session. According to [Commands available while rebasing (GitHub documentation)](https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-rebase/):

> `pick` simply means that the commit is included. Rearranging the order of the pick commands changes the order of the commits when the rebase is underway. If you choose not to include a commit, you should delete the entire line.